# SVN process : Client specific development in branch

Tags: svn, architecture, branching-and-merging

This is what my SVN structure looks like, for my java based product:

> \branches
>    \clientA 
> \trunk 
> \tags

**Client A** specific product customization is being done in `clientA` branch. Once the customization for release is finished, the branch will be *tagged* and *released*. Now, I am **not** going to merge these changes to `Trunk` because these are client specific changes.

Let's say, I've made a release `MyProduct-ClientA-REL-v1.0`.
**Client A** requests more features / enhancements. So, I continue to develop in the same branch, getting ready for the next release (`MyProduct-ClientA-REL-v1.1`). While developing for this release, **Client A** comes back and says that he has encountered a bug with the previous release.

What do I do now? Say, I have modified too many things in the same branch of the v1.0 code (deleted files).

Does the question make sense?

Comment: Why not including the bug fix in REL 1.1?

Comment: This is a hotfix - it has to go now - can't wait.

Comment: Hmm. you could modify REL 1.0, release it as 1.01 and merge it later onto REL 1.1

Comment: REL1.0 is a tag. Do you mean to say I need to create a new hotfix branch, copying it from /tags/MyProduct-ClientA-REL-v1.0 ? and make changes to it and release it? I don't probably have to merge this code into REL1.1 coz the files being fixed as part of hotfix are not present in REL1.1. They were removed in 1.1 coz they are not required.

Comment: Copy your tag REL 1.0 to a new hotfix/feature branch. Make your changes, tag it as REL 1.01 and delete the feature branch again. Later on, before you release 1.1 you need to merge your tag REL 1.01 into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do.

Export the clientA tag at the time of the release (if you didn't make it a tag, you will have to do some research to find which revision it is equivalent to). Also, if you didn't make a tag before, after finding the revision is a good moment to do it.

With that, create an additional branch for that release bugs. Make your fix and commit into the given branch. Get a diff with the release version and fix it in your client main branch.

For other customizations, maybe it would be a good idea to create a branch 'ClientX' and, there, recreate the trunk/branchs/tags structure.

Comment: what is the difference between exporting the tag to a branch to copying the tag to a branch?

Comment: I meant `export` as "export given revision/tag to your HDD so you can work on it". You can instead first copy the tag to the branch and then just export the branch.